# Pragmatically export Alloy Instances to a file

Tags: alloy

I have an Alloy model.  The model is of some decision making logic in software I wrote.  In that model I have a few predicates that create examples.  The predicate creates instances that are expected behavior and outside expected behavior.  I would love to take those examples as inputs to a unit test for my code.

Does anyone have an example of some software that interacts with Alloy to dump many examples generated to a single file? I would love to run a program, get a file with many instances in it, and then use that file as input to my test program.

This interests me because the examples and counter examples created are often not what I would think to do when hand writing my test inputs.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can export an instance in the File/Export To menu.

If you can work in Java, then maybe it is interesting to know we're setting up an open source repo on github: https://github.com/AlloyTools/

I think it is quite easy to link your code with this code and generate your test cases or provide them from proper files.

I am extremely interested in this kind of applications for Alloy so please keep us posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/alloytools

Comment: I prefer Java, so that is a good sign!  Which part of the repo should i look into?

Comment: I am pretty new to the Alloy code but I created the repo. We publish snapshots to org.alloytools:org.alloytools.alloy.dist:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT in   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots repo. If you put that on your classpath you have all the Alloy code, including the native SAT solvers. I would look at https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/blob/3bf49ba02423c13fa2a9e425bead052047064b4b/org.alloytools.alloy.application/src/test/java/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole/InternalTest.java#L129. The A4Solution contains a set of tuples with the current solution.